# Redirect github default homepage to my own page

Tags: github, github-pages

i have recently create a github page but the default homepage is always [this auto-generated homepage](https://congminh090800.github.io/TheBoys-WebDevelopment--18_31/)

But I directly want to go to my actual webpage,is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of [Using meta refresh to create an instant client-side redirect](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html): there is no space.

```html
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
  <head>      
    <title>The Tudors</title>      
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://thetudors.example.com/'" />    
  </head>    
  <body> 
    <p>This page has moved to a <a href="http://thetudors.example.com/">
      theTudors.example.com</a>.</p> 
  </body>  
</html>
```

But in your case, your [`index.html`](https://github.com/congminh090800/TheBoys-WebDevelopment--18_31/blob/314c0117bccd32d0fc9eba3aaa645455ac862257/index.html) does work on my side, and does redirect to [`default.html`](https://congminh090800.github.io/TheBoys-WebDevelopment--18_31/default.html).